# ExecutorServicve.invokeAll() doesn't go into Call()

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executorservice, callable

Running into a strange situation. When I locally debug my project, in the same project's unit tests, ExecutorService invokeAll correctly goes into the call() method.

However, when I test my project as a part of a larger project (my project included as jar - I have triple verified the dependency is running latest code), the exectorService.invokeAll(Tasks) does not go into call(). Here is sample code:

```
public class ReaderWithBusinessRulesImpl implements Callable<List<FsDealWrapper>> {

@Override
public List<FsDealWrapper> call() throws Exception{
    return read(deals, context, cobFrom, cobTo);
}
```

The class that executes these Runnable tasks

```
final List<ReaderWithBusinessRulesImpl> tasks = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (List<FsDeal> dealsChunk : Lists.partition(req.getDeals(), readSize)) {
        tasks.add(new ReaderWithBusinessRulesImpl(fsDao, dealRequestsGenerator, dealsChunk, req.getContext(), cobFrom, cobTo));
    }
    try {
        for (Future<List<FsDealWrapper>> results : service.invokeAll(tasks)) {
```

This last line (Above) only correctly goes into the call() method when executing locally, but not in another project.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I previously didnt mark my call() method with @Override annotation. Including @Override now gives me what I expected.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other problem. the solution seems bit weird to me

Comment: The `@Override` annotation is only for compile-time safety; there **must** have been another issue.

Comment: @JacobG it seems this fixed it for my program, there was no other change that I made. It's a bit skeptical to me too, but I'll take it... for now.....